# "no element found" using xml.etree.ElementTree with XML file from the web

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Here's the Python source:

```py
fsock = urllib2.urlopen('http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/cgi/exportview/divisions/uos-fp/2009/XML/uos-fp_2009.xml')

doc=et.parse(fsock)
```

When I tried to run this it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\reading and writing xml file from web1.py", line 30, in 
    doc=et.parse(fsock)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1176, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 654, in parse
    self._root = parser.close()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1635, in close
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1487, in _raiseerror
    raise err
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

Can any one help as to why this is happening?

Comment: Post your real code. What you have works for me.

Comment: Can you actually open that URL in a browser and retrieve the XML? The error sounds like a premature EOF on the input stream when executing `et.parse()`.

Comment: The code works:  
import urllib2  
from xml.etree.cElementTree import parse, dump  

fsock = urllib2.urlopen('http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/cgi/exportview/divisions/uos-fp/2009/XML/uos-fp_2009.xml')  

doc = parse(fsock)  
dump(doc)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works:

```py
import urllib2  
from xml.etree.cElementTree import parse, dump  

fsock = urllib2.urlopen('http://eprints.soton.ac.uk/cgi/exportview/divisions/uos-fp/2009/XML/uos-fp_2009.xml')

doc = parse(fsock)  
dump(doc)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but it seems that it would never stop, sort of infinite iteration